# jQuery append function not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Why is my jQuery append function not working in IE8

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRows()
{ 
    i=1;
    $("#MyTable").append('<tr><td><input type=checkbox  name=rowchk\<%=i%> value="checkbox" checked="checked" style="display: none;" /></td>'
    +'<td>Cheque / DD no<input type="text" name="cheque_txt1" /></td>'
    +'<td>Cheque/DD Date<input type="text" name="date_txt1" /></td>'
    +'<td>Bank Name <input type="text" name="bank_txt1" /></td>'
    +' <td>Pay Amount   <input type="text" name="amount_txt1" /></td>'
    +'</tr>');
i++;
}</script>
```

Error shown by IE8

> Message: Object expected

Comment: It works fine on mozilla and firefox...

Comment: Show your html please

Comment: `<%=i%>` is invalid html

Comment: its a scriplet tag coz we r using jsp

Comment: The JSP tag won't execute.  JSP runs on the server side, and JavaScript (including jQuery) runs client-side.  By the time your jQuery runs, the JSP processing is done.

Comment: first declare i. var i = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that document is ready. Have you tried calling the function from jquery document.ready? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
<script>

    $(function() {

          // Call your functions
          addRows();

    });

</script>
```